# WordPress Htaccess breaking rest of site

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

To start, I am hosting my website on AWS. I have a normal WordPress site in the root, with a custom application in a sub-folder. The Htaccess in the sub-folder is:

```
//Htaccess
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

And the Htaccess in the root:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I have a feeling WordPress is screwing up my application in /sub/, cause it was working before I moved Wordpress to the root. If you need additional info, let me know. How do I get Wordpress to ignore that directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add default htaccess for root directory of wordpress site.
Read out the documentation [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess) for basic , subdomains , multisite etc.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Place this htaccess in sub folder.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: @Garrettj944 is your sub folder application on wordpress or custom PHP script ?